# GraphDB account modeling: user access relationship attribute or relationship?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am attempting to model account access in a graph DB.

The account can have multiple users and multiple features. A user can have access to many accounts. Each account can give access to only part of the features for each user.

One way I see it is to represent access for each user through relationship attributes, this allows having a shared feature node.

user_1 has access to account_1-feature_1 and account_2-feature-2. user_1 does not have access to account_1-feature_2 even though it is enabled for the account.

[image]

Another way to model the same access, but without relationship attribute is to create account specific feature nodes.

[image]

Question 1: which of these 2 ways is a more 'proper' modeling in the graph DB world?

Now to make things more interesting the account can also have parts which can be accessed by multiple accounts and a certain feature should be able to be scoped down to only be accessible for specific part by user.

In this example user_1 can access account_1 only for part_a feature_1.

[image]

To me it seems like defining an attribute on relationship is the way to go for being able to scope down user access by feature & by part of the account. However, reading neo4j powerpoints this would be one of the code smells of relationships having "Lots of attribute-like properties". Is there a better way to approach such problem in a graph?

Comment: Depending on the scale of your database, I would prefer the first one. Besides, it is harder to maintain the second approach because you would have to create/modify the node featureX_accountY everytime you make changes on the account or features or both. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but here are my thoughts. Option 1 definitely sounds the better way from a modeling perspective, however, I don't see how you can keep the data consistent without building heavy machinery to do it. For example, If someone deletes Account1.Feature1, and does not update the edge from User1 -> Account1, then you end up having stale RBAC rules in the system. You think you have access to something, but in reality that "thing" does not exist anymore. Option 2 may not seem very attractive from a data model perspective, but it does keep your data consistent. If you delete Account1.Feature1, the edge is automatically deleted in the same transaction.

The only con is that, you need to incur additional cost at insertion where you need to insert a lot more nodes than Option 1. For an RBAC system, I think its a fair compromise.

The same comment applies to the second half of your question as well.